# How do I get the group of a Cognito user in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a Spring project and have used AWS Cognito for authentication. That was relatively easy to set by following a tutorial like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-cognito). But there's no real details on how to get the user *group*.

Is there any easy way to get the group of an AWS Cognito user within a Spring application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Please login to Cognito User Pool
- select users and group
- In the right pane there are 2 tabs, user and group
- select group and create a new group
- move the required user into this group
- set the IAM role and permission to the group
- We use API gateway to do authorisation where we check the user group and associated permissions. JWT tokens generated from Cognito Identity Pool consists of the group details and this info can be used by your client program or server program.